# Feed jacoco coverage report to SonarQube using TeamCity but it shows 0% coverage

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, teamcity, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a gradle project with some codes in `src/main/java` and some unit tests in `src/test/java`

Below is snippet from **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDir 'src/main/java' }
    }
}

test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.8"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

On TeamCity, I have 2 steps, first is Gradle step with command `gradle clean jacocoTestReport build` and second step is **SonarQube runner** with the following parameters:

```
-Dsonar.sources=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/src
-Dsonar.java.binaries=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/build/classes
-Dsonar.branch.name=%teamcity.build.branch%
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/build/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec
```

However, on SonarQube dashboard, my project still shows to have **0% Coverage**. Please advise me if I feed `jacoco` coverage report correctly to SonarQube (Version 6.7)

Comment: Did you have a look at the SonarQube log files?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I can't see the log as I have no control of that SonarQube server (it's managed by another team)

Comment: What does the log of the analysis tells you ? why don't you use SonarQube scanner for gradle ? SonarRunner is deprecated if i'm correct you should be using sonar scanner anyway.

Comment: @benzonico Sonar Runner is a dedicated build step in TeamCity.

Comment: Also, the admin of SonarQube server prevents any local analyis results from being pushed directly to server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using TeamCity JaCoCo integration for Gradle runner the coverage should be automatically. Make sure you've provided "Binaries location:" in the SonarQube Runner. In this case the build log will contain such lines:

```
 # before SonarQube start:
 -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
 -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=/.../buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/JACOCO8457480821230827929coverage/jacoco.exec

 # while SonarQube is executed:
 Sensor JaCoCoSensor
 Analysing /.../buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/JACOCO8457480821230827929coverage/jacoco.exec
```

In case you want to use JaCoCo plugin in your Gradle script you should manually set coverage type and data location in the SonarQube Runner step

```
-Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/build/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec
```

So try to add "sonar.java.coveragePlugin" property

Comment: HI @linfar, May i check that for binaries location, will it be location of the compiled classes or the instrumented classes?

Comment: @hydradon I've never run JaCoCo in offline mode. [Documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html) says you have to target initial compiled classes, not instrumented.